# Git warnings when updating homebrew OS X

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

```
Last login: Mon Mar  7 17:35:51 on console
~ brew update
warning: unable to access '/Users/Jason/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '/Users/Jason/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
Updated Homebrew from 7f8aa6d to d08692f.
==> New Formulae
cucumber-cpp               prometheus                 znapzend
==> Updated Formulae
afl-fuzz            gtk+                orc                 writerperfect
crystal-lang        kafka               platformio
dependency-check    libvirt             sslscan
ghq                 logtalk             syncthing
~
```

I'm running El Capitan on my macbook and whenever I try to update homebrew I'm getting those warnings. I'm looking for a solution on how I can stop these warnings from happening.

Comment: Have you tried running the command as `sudo`? **sudo** = authenticate yourself a superuser to gain extra security privileges

Comment: When I try to do "sudo brew update" I get
Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew update'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't run `brew` with root privileges unless really needed. Run `brew doctor` and check the permissions on `/Users/Jason/.config`:

```
chown -R Jason:staff ~/.config
chmod -R 744 ~/.config
```

Comment: @koven: Please mark this answer as the accepted one if it helped you. Otherwise it would be nice if you'd explain why it did not help you.

Comment: The `chown` and `chmod` commands above have solved my issue with the brew warnings. However I had to run them using `sudo command`.

Comment: Before running both commands I wanted to `ls -l ~/.config` first and indeed I had to run `sudo ls -l ~/.config` and noticed the directories were owned by root:staff.
`192-168-0-112:~ $ sudo ls -ltr /Users/myusername/.config
Password:
total 0
drwx------  3 root  staff  102 Jan  5 14:20 htop`

Comment: Note: this situation can occur if you run any command with `sudo`, if it creates the `~/.config` dir. E.g. `sudo htop`.

Answer (score 4):

based on R.Q's answer, just in case a complete noob like me hit this question.
here are 2 lines to copy and paste:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config
sudo chmod -R 744 ~/.config
```

The reason for

```
> brew install somepackage
warning: unable to access '/Users/username/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
```

appearing is as wisbucky's comment, sudo'ing some commands like htop.

once you run the commands above, running 'sudo htop' again should no longer cause issues!